# Revoke token. RestTemplate using issue

Tags: java, spring, rest, google-api-client, spring-rest

I'm trying to revoke google token following [API](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#tokenrevoke) (`"Content-type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`, request type `POST`, `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/revoke?token={token}`).

My code example is:

```
private static final String REVOKE_URL = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/revoke";
private static final String TOKEN = "token";
@Autowired
private RestTemplate restTemplate;

public void revokeToken(TokenDetailsDto tokenDetailsDto) {
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add(CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE);
    HttpEntity<?> entity = new HttpEntity(headers);
    Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<>();
    parameters.put(TOKEN, tokenDetailsDto.getRefreshToken());
    LOGGER.info("used parameters:\n\turl={},\n\tentity={},\n\turiParameters={}", REVOKE_URL, entity, uriParameters);
    restTemplate.exchange(REVOKE_URL, HttpMethod.GET, entity, Void.class, parameters);
}
```

result is exception:

```
17:30:54,323 INFO  # com.nextiva.calendar.client.google.GoogleRevokeAccessService.revokeToken used parameters:
  url=https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/revoke,
  entity=<{Content-Type=[application/x-www-form-urlencoded]}>,
  uriParameters={token=1/mzMH8VPrltarCo3LOHU_tBWi4qK5e20uIM0R_Al9T34}
17:31:20,718 ERROR # com.nextiva.calendar.web.error.handling.BaseExceptionHandler.exception 400 Bad Request
org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 400 Bad Request
  at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:63)
  at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:700)
  at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:653)
  at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:621)
  at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:540)
```

I try use rest client to handle request like in documentation it is ok  (using rest client I tried to use POST request with specified content type).

Same error result if I use

```
restTemplate.postForEntity(REVOKE_URL, entity, Void.class, uriParameters);
```

---

So issue is in restTemplate using (my spring part). Is any ideas, what I've done wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is:

```
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE);
    HttpEntity<?> entity = new HttpEntity(headers);
    UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(REVOKE_URL)
            .queryParam("token", tokenDetailsDto.getRefreshToken());
    LOGGER.info("used parameters:\n\turl={},\n\tentity={},\n\turiParameters={}", REVOKE_URL, entity);
    restTemplate.postForObject(builder.build().encode().toUri(), entity, Void.class);
```

Small explanation: service expect urlParameters, but `parameters` was not urlParameters, its request parameters. So I used `UriComponentsBuilder` to build correct request.